# MiKTeX install fails

Tags: errors, installing, miktex, windows

I'm trying to install Basic MiKTeX 2.9 on Windows 7 to the default location and I'm receiving the following error:

[image]

Has anyone seen this issue before?

The message says

> ```
> The operation could not operated for the following reasons:
> Windows API error 2: The system cannot find the file specified.
>
> Details: C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tpm\packages\enctex.tpm
> ```

Comment: I can't read the message in your screenshots. But if you want to install miktex only for yourself I would not install it in the default location but in some folder outside C:\program files (and without admin rights but simply with your user rights in single user mode).

Comment: Installing it to `.../Documents/MiKTeX2.9` rather then in `.../Program Files/MiKTeX2.9` did the trick and I verified the install with the `latex --version` command.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is caused by an issue with user rights in Windows.